# Replace xib file with Main.storyboard file in App delegate class

Tags: iphone, appdelegate

Right now project is using MainWindow.xib in App delegate class as main nib file. It has this code in main.m file

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
}
```

I want to replace it with Mainstoryboard. I changed it in the info.plist file as Mainstoryboard file base name but it shows error that **there is no app delegate set. An app delegate class must be specified to use a main storyboard file**.

What coding i should do in App delegate class to use Mainstoryboard file.

Thanks

Comment: Note for anyone arriving here from Google looking for the error message the OP got: moving to Storyboards is actually the solution if you are still using nib files.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Replace the last argument (`nil`) of the `UIApplicationMain()` function with the name of the app delegate class. It's generally `@"AppDelegate"` by default.

Answer (score 17):

In case others find this as I have, the code you actually want to replace `nil` with is `NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])` where you would replace `AppDelegate` with your classname if you have named yours differently.

Also, don't forget to `#import "AppDelegate.h"`