# Is it possible to add storyboard in a project where a project made without stroyboard i.e Programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I want to add StoryBoard to a project which is made programmatically is it possible to do so.

Comment: I am doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add new storyboard to Xcode project. I am sharing following screenshot please check this:[image: add New Storyboard]

You can give name to that storyboard.

Comment: Ok than how i will call this stroyboard in my code.

Comment: As @Mr.UB said add name of that storyboard into your **.plist** file

Comment: Can you please tell us, what exact problem you are facing?

Comment: check this @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973286/adding-storyboard-to-existing-project

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add storyboard manually, but you have to set its value in the `.plist` file.

[image: plist file]

Make appdelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` code like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

It should be empty.

Comment: Ok than how i will call this stroyboard in my code.

Comment: Have you initialized root view in your appdelegate? If so than remove that code, your storyboard will open automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use several storyboards. If the project is huge, it makes sense to break the UI into several logical storyboards and to link one to another using the code or a storyboard reference.
[image]